# $ (jQuery) symbol = null, but "jQuery(...)" works

Tags: jquery, datatable, null, selector

I'm having trouble with jQuery lately.

For instance I'd like to select a text Input and change its value :

```
var myInput = jQuery('#myInput');
myInput[0].value = "something"; // this works* but text remins grey, and clears as soon as the input gets focus
myInput[0].val("something"); // I believe this is what I should use, however it pops an error :error ²
myVar = $("#something"); // Returns Null (actually, even if I see the function in the debugger that's supposed to return the elements)
```

*the selector actually is something like : "#aDiv #anOther #anOther #aTable[aDynamicID] tFoot tr[name=[aDymanicName]]"

it works but it's complicated, so I just wrote #something ;)

error ² : **Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'val'**

Any one understands jQuery enough to see what's going on?? :(

I'm trying to insert filters into a DataTable programatically, here's my `<head>` :

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="parminou_style.css" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jscript/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jscript/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jscript/prototype.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jscript/scriptaculous.js" ></script>
    <script src="jscript/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="parminou_js.js" ></script>

    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jscript/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jscript/jeditable.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jscript/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js">    </script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jscript/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script> 

    <!-- src="jquery-1.10.1.min.js" -->
    <link href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
    <link href="css/jquery.dataTabl
```

sry, it kinda looks like a mess. :/

Comment: That doesn't make any sense... are you sure you're using `jQuery` and not `$`? `jQuery()` should not be returning the dom node unless you're using `.get()` or `[n]` on an existing collection(which you aren't in the given code.)

Comment: OMG, Do you really need all those libraries?

Comment: If what you describe is correct, something is actually overriding `jQuery` which would be very rare.

Comment: Oh crap, I'm writing a simplyfied code to remove useless lines, AND I FORGOT myVar IS AN ARRAY.   So it should be : myVar[0].val/value

Comment: well of course `myVar[0].val` is undefined. `myVar` is NOT AN ARRAY! it's an array-like Object. `myVar.val()` will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example to insert filter in Data Table

var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
  oTable.fnFilter( 'test string' );

More details on how to add a filter in Data Table can be found in the following location
https://datatables.net/api

Also appropriate elements can be selected using jquery using CSS selectors
e.g  can be selected as,

jQuery(".test")  or  jQuery("#input1")

if the selected component is a text input , val() will surely work on that

Comment: however, even if it weren't a text input, .val would still be defined. It shouldn't be throwing the error presented.

Comment: Like Kevin said, I'm definitively getting the input, .value works, but the text then changes on the focus event :/... I'll try fn(filter though, but i'd apreciate to have the filter text in the inpus field... So I'll try and tell you news)

Comment: Ok, works perfectly! I've had a bad time with it... just because I forgot the "#" in front of my Id! ^^'   (btw I don't usually do this, in this post I did, but it wasn't code, it was an example >.> )

Answer (score 1):

Of course `myVar = $("something");`  will return null. Do you have an element called <something>?

You forgot #, which indicates an ID.
Use . to indicate classes.
Use without prefix like above, to select tag names.

I just saw your edit (which makes this answer no longer apply). Help us by posting some of the relevant HTML. Also make sure $ is defined correctly and not affected by the other scripts that you have--their docs will probably tell you.

Comment: sorry, Actually "#something" is much more complex : "#aDiv #anOther #anOther #aTable[aDynamicID] tFoot tr[name=[aDymanicName]]".... see why I wrote "something" instead?

Comment: `$` is prototype, not jQuery in this case.

Comment: Okay then this answer is utterly useless. sorry

Comment: Does prototype multiple selectors require a comma between the selectors? maybe that's why you get null.

Answer (score 0):

`myInput` is NOT an array, it's an array-like object. using `[0]` on it returns the first dom node in the jQuery collection. That is why `.value` works and `.val` does not. DOM Nodes don't have a `.val` method while jQuery collections do.

```
var myInput = jQuery('#myInput');
myInput[0].value = "something"; // this works* but text remains grey, and clears as soon as the input gets focus
myInput.val("something"); // this works* but text remains grey, and clears as soon as the input gets focus
myVar = $("#something"); // is prototype
```

As far as it remaining grey, you haven't done anything that would make it not be grey. As far as it changing as soon as it gets focused, something else is doing that, not this code.